# error: expected initializer before ‘COUNT_TYPE’ in a typedef expression

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int64_t  COUNT_TYPE;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when compiling, it says:
main.cpp|4|error: expected initializer before ‘COUNT_TYPE’|

Comment: This is your compiler's rather obtuse way of telling you that `unsigned int64_t` is not a type. `std::uint64_t`, `unsigned long long`, etc. are viable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `unsigned int`, the `unsigned` does not "modify" the `int`; the type is "`unsigned int`".

**You cannot "add" `unsigned` or `signed` to an existing type name.**

Instead of taking `int64_t` and trying to convert it into an unsigned type, use an unsigned type to begin with, such as `uint64_t`.

And don't forget to include `<cstdint>` so that you actually have access to these types.

Answer (score 0):

int64_t is a typedef of fundamental integer type. So you need to add the definition of it. include `cstdint` in your program as follows. `#include <cstdint>` and there's already unsigned int64 typedefs are available. `uint64_t`